# Show that $U$ commutes with $T$ if and only if $U$ commutes with each $T_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a normal operator on a finite-dimensional complex inner product space $V$. Use the spectral decomposition $T=\lambda_1T_1+\dots+\lambda_kT_k$ to prove that if $U$ is a linear operator on $V$, then if $U$ commutes with $T$, $U$ commutes with each $T_i$.

$UT=TU$

$U(\lambda_1T_1+\dots+\lambda_kT_k)=(\lambda_1T_1+\dots+\lambda_kT_k)U$

Couple things I have tried are to plug in an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors and to use the fact that $g(T)=\sum_{i=1}^k g(\lambda_i)T_i$ if $g$ is a polynomial but neither led anywhere.

Other post said that because a polynomial $g_i$ such that $g_i(T)=T_i$ can be defined for each $i$, then $g_i(T)U=Ug_i(T)$ however I fail to see why you can ignore the $U$ when taking the $g_i$ of both sides?

Comment: Try making the polynomial a little more explicit as a sum of powers of $T$ each multiplied by some scalar. If $U$ commutes with $T$ it commutes with any power of $T$ (by induction), $U$ certainly commutes with any scalar, therefore...

Comment: So the issue is we do *not* take the $g$ of "both sides" but rather show that $g(T)$ commutes with $U$. Thank you very much. @SebastianSchoennenbeck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{split}
g(T)U&=(\alpha_nT^n+\dots+\alpha_0)U\\
&=U(\alpha_nT^n+\dots+\alpha_0)\\
&=Ug(T)
\end{split}

Then let $g(T)=g_i(T)=T_i$ for all $i$ (as each $T_i$ is a polynomial in $T$, $g_i(T)$)